# Redux saga event channel is terminated after another saga is executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using saga `eventChannel` to listen to events that are being triggered(maybe WebSocket in the actual app), and then I am updating my Redux Store. In component, I am calling an API action. Then an interval(polling), which is being handled by a saga. I am attaching my event listener once API succeeded for the first time.

After 2nd API call my `eventChannel` is terminated somehow.

**EventListner:**

```
function* countDownSaga(value) {
  const chan = yield call(countdown, value)
  try {    
    while (true) {
      // take(END) will cause the saga to terminate by jumping to the finally block
      let seconds = yield take(chan)
      console.log(`countdown: ${seconds}`)
    }
  } finally {
    console.log('countdown terminated')
  }
}
```

**Api saga:**

```js
var countDownStarted = false

// Function to be called by saga taking action CALL_FAKE_API
function* fetchData() {
  // Simulate some server delay
  yield delay(1500)
  // Call a function
  // redux-saga "call" effect allows you to call a function
  const result = yield call(getUserData)
  yield put({ type: RECORD_USER, result })
  if(!countDownStarted) {
        yield fork(countDownSaga, 100)
        countDownStarted= true
  }
}
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2d9L8fse/2/

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is not the event channel that is terminated, it goes to the finally block because the saga itself is canceled. That is because you use `takeLatest` to run the fetchData saga:

```
yield takeLatest(CALL_FAKE_API, fetchData)
```

And in your react component you are dispatching the CALL_FAKE_API action every 15 seconds:

```
componentDidMount() {
      const { callFakeApi } = this.props
      callFakeApi()
      this.timer = setInterval(function () { callFakeApi() }, 15 * 1000)
}
```

If one fetchData saga is already running and you dispatch the `CALL_FAKE_API` again, `takeLatest` will cancel the previous saga - including all its attached children like the `countDownSaga` saga.

You can try e.g. replacing the `fork` effect with `spawn` which creates a detached task, that is not canceled even if the fetchData saga is canceled.

```
yield spawn(countDownSaga, 100)
```

If you don't need to cancel the fetch itself, you can also just replace `takeLatest` with `takeEvery` and avoid the cancelation altogether.